# Is there a way to plot columns with the same name as the same colour?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-processing

I am attempting to plot one dataset which has many columns with the same name. I was trying to reuse a plotting program I made earlier, but the issue is that it plots each column in a different colour, instead I would like each column with the **same name** to be the **same colour**. Furthermore, it adds each column to the legend causing a lot of mess in the figure which I have attached. Is there a way to just put one label per colour? Any help to fix these issues would be greatly appreciated!

[Here is an example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhsxs.jpg) As you can see instead of plotting both "O" as one colour, it plots it as two since there are two columns of data, and created a duplicate in the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

s = pd.read_csv('Edit_This.csv') # reads the .csv file can be found in dropbox > shared manuscripts > Ravi Ben MoOx Nucleation and LEIS > Figures

xmin = 0 # Change these bounds as needed
xmax = 1
ymin = 0
ymax = 2500

y_axis_columns = s.columns[1:] # Reads column data to plot y values from index 1 onwards

for col_name in y_axis_columns: # Loop to plot all columns until it finds an empty one
   plt.plot(s.depth,s[col_name], label=col_name)
   plt.tight_layout()
   from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
   axes = plt.gca()
   axes.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
   axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
   axes.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
   plt.xlabel('Depth (nm)', fontsize=12) # Edit as needed
   plt.ylabel('Intensity (counts/nC)', fontsize=12) 
   plt.legend(loc='upper center', fontsize=10) # Defines legend formatting
   plt.savefig("6_Sputter1_5-222cyc_SiOx.png", dpi = 1200) # Edit export file name and DPI here
plt.show()
```

You can download the data from this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Bb-uDDsFTgMXvaRZ7VAEydNLqmA4zZ9b/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem emerges because you have multiple columns with the same name. So, you need to handle that. The following code does so:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

s = pd.read_csv('Edit_This.csv') # reads the .csv file can be found in dropbox > shared manuscripts > Ravi Ben MoOx Nucleation and LEIS > Figures

xmin = 0 # Change these bounds as needed
xmax = 1
ymin = 0
ymax = 2500

y_axis_columns = s.columns[1:] # Reads column data to plot y values from index 1 onwards


# this is the color dictionary
colors = {"O": 'r', "Mo": 'b', 'Al':'g'}

for col_name in y_axis_columns: # Loop to plot all columns until it finds an empty one
   plt.plot(s.depth,s[col_name], label=col_name, color=colors[col_name.split('.')[0]])
   plt.tight_layout()
   from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
   axes = plt.gca()

axes.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
axes.set_ylim(ymin,ymax)
plt.xlabel('Depth (nm)', fontsize=12) # Edit as needed
plt.ylabel('Intensity (counts/nC)', fontsize=12) 

# Defines legend formatting
custom_lines = [Line2D([0], [0], color='r', lw=4),
                Line2D([0], [0], color='b', lw=4),
                Line2D([0], [0], color='g', lw=4)]
plt.legend(custom_lines, ['O', 'Mo', 'Al'], loc='upper center', fontsize=10)

plt.savefig("6_Sputter1_5-222cyc_SiOx.png", dpi = 1200) # Edit export file name and DPI here
plt.show()
```

Which produces the following image:
[image]

Comment: I guess one last question, not that its too big of an issue, but is there anyway to eliminate the need to keep adding O.x (where x is each additional O column) to the code? This would just result in a more robust solution that would be able to take any dataset and produce a plot. Again not too pressing of an issue, just curious if its doable.

Comment: Wow, just a few characters. Do you mind explaining how "color=colors[col_name.split('.')[0]]" fixed that issue?

Comment: no problem... `col_name` could be `O`, `O.1`, `O.2`, ...etc..As you can see, we only interested in the part before `.`. So, we need to split it based on `.` and then choose the first part. So, `"O.1".split('.')[0]` will be just `O`